# Can I use "stand someone up" for a friend ?

Tags: phrase-usage

According to Oxford dictionary, **stand someone up** means:

> Fail to keep an appointment with a boyfriend or girlfriend

However, according to Cambridge, simply:

> To fail to meet someone you had arranged to see

Can I use it for an appointment with a friend? If not, what are the most used alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the phrase can be used in the context of a platonic friendship, although I believe you’ll find it most often used in the context of a date. That said, here is one example where the context seems to be outside of a romantic relationship:

> After having missed several lunch appointments with a friend, the student made plans to meet a friend for lunch. At 5 o’clock the student realized: *"I **stood up** my friend again"*.
>
> <sup>Source: *The Self-Conscious Emotions: Theory and Research*, 2013</sup>

It looks like Oxford focuses on the most common use of the term in its definition, while Cambridge defines the phrasal verb more broadly. I wouldn’t call either definition wrong; I’d just say that Oxford’s might be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One additional question, if I miss an appointment with a friend then, is this the phrase to go or is there some other more appropriate expression?

Comment: @PesaThe - There is no single phrase that must be used. You can say, “I missed the appointment,” “I forgot about the appointment,” “I was a no-show,” among others.